# Weekly alternating cronjob (with step values)

Tags: cron

I want a cronjob to run on every 1st and 3rd Saturday in a month and another one to run every 2nd and 4th Saturday. Now crond offers "step values":

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with "" specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For example, "0-23/2" can be used  in
>          the  hours  field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22").  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk,
>          so if you want to say "every two hours", just use "*/2".

But if I use

```
30 3 * * 6/2 command
```

both scripts run (indeterministically) on every second Saturday. What is the right way to get them to run alternating?

I know the possibility of a wrapper script, but I want to avoid it if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

Since you know that one and only one Saturday will occur in the first 7 days of any month, you can follow that pattern and use the `day-of-month` field to keep each job separate:

```
30 3 1-7,15-21 * 6 script1
30 3 8-14,22-28 * 6 script2
```

Thus `script1` will always catch the first and third saturdays and `script2` will always catch the second and fourth.

Comment: This approach does not work! From the cron man page: "The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields --- day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (ie, aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time. For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday."

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the cron #?

30 3 * * 6#1 Firstandthirdcommand 
30 3 * * 6#3 Firstandthirdcommand 
30 3 * * 6#2 SecondAndfourthCommand 
30 3 * * 6#4 SecondAndfourthCommand

Hash ( # )
    '#' is allowed for the day-of-week field, and must be followed by a number between one and five. It allows you to specify constructs such as "the second Friday" of a given month

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  What versions of cron support this?  I don't doubt it, and it's a useful concept, but I don't see it in the `man 5 crontab` of a recent CentOS box, for example.

Comment: The only source is the said Wikipedia article where the corresponding paragraph is marked with "citation needed". Are there any other reliable sources? I could not google anything.

Comment: That is decidedly non-standard! The Wikipedia article has been improved somewhat and now reads:  *"The following are non-standard characters and **exist only in some cron implementations** , such as Quartz java scheduler"* ...